# Can pulsar timing arrays solve the final parsec problem?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves

To detect gravitational waves from super-massive black holes, you have to use pulsar timing arrays(PTA). Can these detections solve the final parsec problem? If yes, how? If no, is there another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need PTAs to detect gravitational waves from, supermassive black hole binary mergers. Space-based observatories will see these mergers as well.

2) Observing a merger of an SMBH binary would not solve the final parsec problem. This is much more a theoretical problem than that it is an observational problem. The problem is that we do not understand *how* SMBH binaries evolve through the final parsec in separation (in less than a Hubble time).
Observing one would tells us that Nature has found a way, but that is already somewhat evident from the fact that we do not observe loads of galaxies with more than one supermassive black hole at the center (as would have to be the case if all SMBH binaries stalled at around a parsec, given the number of galaxy mergers that must have happened in any galaxy's history.).